# Assigning User to Channel without Object_id

Tags: parse-platform, push-notification

I am currently trying to develop a script for our backend (PHP) which sends push-notifications to a custom group of users using the REST API https://api.parse.com/1/push.

So far, it is working fine sending single push messages and I could probably loop through the list of users and send the push notifications 1by1.
However, this is obviously not a great idea reporting wise since they will show up as single notifications in Parse and hence it would be more difficult to see the open rate, etc.

My Idea would be to assign a unique Channel to the users which match the filters defined and sends the push to this channel.
I know that I can do this with the object_id using this:
https://parse.com/docs/rest#installations-updating

But the problem is that I only got the installationID or deviceToken (depending on Device) which I can not use to assign a channel.

It would be great if anybody knows a solution for this using the Data I got (installationID and deviceToken)

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Marco, have a look into the object as, even though their docs don't specify it there is a method to retrieve objectId from the object and pass it to your PHP API.

On Android use:

`ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().getObjectId()`

Nevertheless, if you cannot figure it out, you can always query the installations endpoint of Parse API

`curl -X GET \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: <app-key>" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: <api-key>" \
  -G \
  --data-urlencode 'where={"installationId":"sdfddf-344-dfdf-dffd-dffff"}' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/installations`

To use deviceToken, just edit the where clause.
For more info check their docs [query installations](https://www.parse.com/docs/rest#installations-querying) and [object querying](https://www.parse.com/docs/rest#queries-basic)